# MySql case condition in where clause

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, select, case

This is my table

[image]

My query is when I search using cubbersId, if i got empty data `where cubbersId = 0` else  `where cubbersId = 1 (my_search_data)` its like stored procedure.

I tried this query

```
SELECT * FROM hometestimonial WHERE (CASE 
    WHEN cubbersId IS NOT NULL THEN cubbersId = 1
    ELSE cubbersId = 0
END)
```

I search `cubbersId = 1` so i got `3 datas`. But i tried to search cubbersId = 2 means `no data` in cubbersId 2, so in this case i need to show `cubbersId = 0` data's.

this is my result:

`where cubbersId = 1` datas:

[image]

`where cubbersId = 2` datas:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with UNION ALL.
The 2nd query will return rows only if the 1st is empty:

```
SELECT * FROM hometestimonial
WHERE cubbersId = 2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM hometestimonial
WHERE cubbersId = 0 AND 
NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM hometestimonial
  WHERE cubbersId = 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result you should move the case in select

```
    SELECT *,  CASE 
        WHEN cubbersId IS NOT NULL THEN  1
        ELSE  0
    END my_cubbersId
    FROM hometestimonial
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro here what is `my_cubbersId`

Comment: is an column alias  for avoid name conlict with  cubbersID returned  by select *

Comment: Actually bro i am expecting  same like  @forpas answer. Thanks for you support bro.'

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative:

```
SELECT ht.*
FROM hometestimonial ht
WHERE ht.cubbersId = (SELECT MAX(h2.cubbersID)
                      FROM hometestimonial ht2
                      WHERE cubbersID IN (0, 2)
                     );
```